# SQLServer "El controlador no pudo establecer conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de Sockets seguros <SSL>"

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Desarrollé una `Java Application` la cual realiza consultas e inserciones en base de datos SQL Server. En el computador que la desarrollé ejecuto la aplicación y funciona correctamente, pero cuando la ejecuto desde otro equipo el cual es donde se debe ejecutar, me muestra el siguiente error.

[image: 1.Log]

Código de conexión:

```
public class Model extends Sql {

PreparedStatement s;
//preparando variables necesarias
protected PreparedStatement ps;
protected String bd;
protected Connection cn;
protected Statement st;
protected String sql;
protected ResultSet rs;

String DatoFinales = "";
String driverDataBase = "";

private Connection dbVerificadorConnection;

public Model() throws Exception {

    String sqlserverProperties = Util.getProperties("sqlserver");
    String applicationNameProperties = Util.getProperties("applicationName");
    String databaseNameProperties = Util.getProperties("databaseName");
    String userProperties = Util.getProperties("user");
    String passwordProperties = Util.getProperties("password");
    String driverDataBaseProperties = Util.getProperties("driverDataBase");

    DatoFinales += "jdbc:sqlserver:"
            + sqlserverProperties
            + ";applicationName="
            + applicationNameProperties
            + ";databaseName="
            + databaseNameProperties
            + ";user="
            + userProperties
            + ";password="
            + passwordProperties;

    driverDataBase = driverDataBaseProperties;
}

private void AbrirConexionBaseDatos() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverDataBase); //inicializo el driver             
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatoFinales, new Properties()); //enlazo la tabla   
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        Util.Exception(e);
    }
}

private void CerrarConexionBaseDatos() throws SQLException {
    try {
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Util.Exception(e);
    }
}
```

En la clase `Sql` tengo String con las consultas que realizo.

Comment: Podrías anexar el código de la conexión en Java?

Comment: Listo. Ya lo agregué.

Comment: Has revisado que la dirección del servidor de la BD no sea una local u otra instancia?

Comment: Desde el equipo que estoy intentando ejecutar hago ping a la db y responde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar y probar varias cosas, logré que mi aplicativo se ejecutara correctamente con el Jdk 1.8.0_111, el cual no presentó ningún problema para la conexión con la base de datos SQL que estoy trabajando.

El error se generaba por la versión 200, que al parecer utiliza una conexión mas segura con base de datos SQL.

Comment: Esta opción no debería considerarse viable. Las actualizaciones del JDK han deprecado varios algoritmos inseguros que la industria ha deprecado porque pueden explotarse sus vulnerabilidades. Desde cosas tan simples como montar un certificado para exponer una API por HTTPS, si se habilitan algoritmos inseguros, todo queda expuesto a riesgos graves de seguridad. Usen las versiones más recientes de Java para la compilación que corresponda

Answer (score 3):

Cuando SQL Server se instala, salvo que al hacerlo le indiquemos explícitamente que vamos a utilizar un determinado certificado digital para securizar las comunicaciones, el servidor instala un certificado auto-firmado para ello. Este certificado está creado por el propio SQL Server y no se sustenta en una infraestructura de clave pública real. Lo que quiere decir que el certificado sirve para cifrar las comunicaciones y validar su integridad, pero no sirve para asegurar que nos estamos conectando al servidor correcto, ya que la única "autoridad" que nos asegura que el servidor es el correcto, es el propio servidor.

De eso precisamente es de lo que va ese mensaje de error. Lo que nos indica es que, por defecto, como no se puede verificar la identidad del servidor, no permite la conexión.

FUENTE: https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/resolver-error-al-conectarse-a-sql-server-debido-al-certificado-ssl

al final del string de conexión agregar: TrustServerCertificate=True;

Comment: Esta es la clave del problema. Hay que usar esta opción (idealmente) y/o `encrypt=false;` dependiendo de las características del entorno. Esta opción permite mantener la comunicación cifrada, mientras que la otra devuelve el comportamiento default (sin cifrar)

Answer (score -2):

Después de mucho buscar, encontré esta solución que me funcionó:

Me dirigí hacia esta ubicación:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkXXX/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/Java.security

Para Windows C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXX\jre\lib\security

Comenté esta línea:

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms = SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize <1024,\EC
keySize <224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL

Funcionó para mi

Comment: Esta opción habilita algoritmos deprecados o con graves vulnerabilidades de seguridad. Incluso para aplicaciones que sí usen comunicación segura con la BD y otros componentes. Suena a una mala idea

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Efectivamente supone un grave problema de seguridad. Soy consiente que no es la mejor opción. Sin embargo, esto fue lo único que me resolvió el problema, al menos momentáneamente en el entorno de desarrollo para poder avanzar, mientras encuentro como solucionarlo para el ambiente productivo.