# Conexión de Java y SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando hacer una conexión entre una BD y Java, sólo que me marca el siguiente error

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL). Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:934e36ca-d468-49e9-a1f4-7d524457cb1b`

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class Conexion {
    
    Connection conect = null;
    
    public Connection getConexion() {
        
        try {
            String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DEPENDENCIAS";
            conect = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, "usersql", "clave123");
            System.out.println("Conectado.");
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return conect;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Conexion().getConexion();
    }

}
```

Comment: [esto resuleve tu pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236148/sqlserver-el-controlador-no-pudo-establecer-conexi%C3%B3n-segura-con-sql-server-con)

Comment: Sí, resolvió el problema, igual utilicé la misma versión de jdbc y JDK 8
Gracias!