# Conexion a Base de Datos SQLServer con java

Tags: java, sql-server

El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL)

Ayuda... al ejecutar el codigo me sale este error

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            try {
                String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=maestro_01";
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Conexion fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Versión de SQL Server?

Comment: puede que esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236148/sqlserver-el-controlador-no-pudo-establecer-conexi%C3%B3n-segura-con-sql-server-con) responda tu duda

Comment: sql server 2019

Comment: Que tipo de conexión usas Conexión integrada de Windows ó Conexión de SQL Server(usuraio y contraseña)?

Comment: Podrías agregar más detalles? Podés realizar una conexión a través de un cliente de base de datos compatible con sql server? Es decir, pudiste corroborar que el servicio de sql server se este ejecutando correctamente? Tenes cargada la lib con el driver jdbc para ese tipo de base de datos? Qué imprime la sentencia `e.printStacktrace()`.

Comment: Buenas, si hice todo eso , ya lo arregle gracias